# Writing .spec files for PostgreSQL isolation tests

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, testing

I am developing a PostgreSQL extension for which I would like to run some tests with concurrent connections. If I understand [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/extend-pgxs.html) correctly, I should be able to do so using the PGXS framework that comes with Postgres. However, it is mentioned that such isolation tests (listed in the `ISOLATION` variable in my `Makefile`) have to be specified in a `.spec` file, and nowhere can I find a mention of how to write such a `.spec` file. I've failed to find an example in the documentation and I've similarly failed to find example code online.

I know how to write the `.sql` tests that one can list in the `REGRESS` variable. Thus, my question is not about how to write tests in general. I specifically would like to know how to write a `.spec` file.

Comment: Have you looked at the examples: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/test/isolation/specs?

Comment: That seems to be indeed what I was looking for, @mustaccio. These files seem readable enough to deduce the working.